# MAN pages for apps installed from sources

Tags: manpage

First I have downloaded GIT using apt-get Debian package management tool. It sucessfully installed version 1.7. After that I downloaded git 1.9 from sources, installed it and removed GIT 1.7 system using apt-get again. Git 1.9 works perfectly, the only problem is I have old man pages ( from 1.7 ) when typing "man git" in console. How to deal with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm sorry, I read your post to quickly.. :D

Edit : 
Debian : https://packages.debian.org/jessie/git-man
Ubuntu : http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/git-man

```
dpkg -i package.deb
```

Comment: my linux release is wheeze ( there is a 1.7 version of GIT). Can I use 1.9 from Jessy distribution ? Maybe it would be more appropriate to use the MAN which I have downloaded from sources ?

Comment: Don't use, use the backport package for your version :https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/git-man